# how to read a list of keywords and put each one at the end of a url

Tags: python, steam

ok, I am trying to make a program which tells the user what steam custom URLs are available from a list they submit but I have only recently started python so I only know a little, I have a working program which allows the user to enter a single keyword and it tells them if the URL is available but I want them to be able to enter a list of keywords and it checks each one of them and prints only the available ones any ideas on how I could do this

my code so far

```
#Steam Custom Url Checker
#Started 21/09/2017
#Finished


import requests

keyword = (input("\n Please enter a keyword "))

url = ("http://steamcommunity.com/id/")

r = requests.get(url + keyword)


if 'The specified profile could not be found.' in r.text:
    print("\n Avaiable Custom Urls")
print("\n", url + keyword)
else :
    print('\nSorry that one is taken')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url = ("http://steamcommunity.com/id/")

#list having the keywords (made by splitting input with space as its delimiter) 
keyword = input().split()

#go through the keywords
for key in keywords :

   #everything else is same logic
   r = requests.get(url + key)

   print("URL :", url+key)
   if 'The specified profile could not be found.' in r.text:
        print("This is available")
   else :
        print('\nSorry that one is taken')
```

That should iterate through your list of keywords and everything else is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

keywords = (raw_input("\n Please enter a list keyword "))

available_keywords =[]
for keyword in keywords.split():
    url = ("http://steamcommunity.com/id/")
    r = requests.get(url + keyword)

    if 'The specified profile could not be found.' in r.text:
        available_keywords.append(url+keyword)

if len(available_keywords) >0:
    print("List of available_keywords : ")
    for url in available_keywords:
        print (url)
else:
    print ("Sorry no url is abailable")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

keyword = (input("\n Please enter the keywords "))
keywords = keyword.split(" ")
url = ("http://steamcommunity.com/id/")
avai = list()

for key in keywords:
    r = requests.get(url + key)
    if 'The specified profile could not be found.' in r.text:
        avai.append(key)

if len(avai)>0:
    print("\n Avaiable Custom Urls")
    for k in avai:
        print("\n", url + k)
else :
    print('\nSorry no url available')
```